# In Teradata, trying to convert Timestamp(6) to timestamp(0)

Tags: teradata

`A` is in the format of `timestamp(6)`. I need it in `timestamp(0)`. The code I am using is the following:

```
cast(cast(A AS date) as timestamp(0))
FROM 'table'
where A >= '?StartDT'
```

After inputing the date I want for the parameter I get the 'Invalid timestamp' error.

Comment: What value exactly are you providing for `?StartDT`

Comment: a date such as '2016-01-01'

Comment: Is column `A` a character field? Does it by chance contain invalid date values? The following doesn't fail: `SELECT CAST(CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP(0))`; suggesting @jnevill is onto something with your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is truly a `Timestamp(6)` then casting it first as a `DATE` will affectively trim off the time elements, so when you cast the result to a `TIMESTAMP(0)` you are going to end up with a time of `00:00:00`.

You'll need to also cast the `TIMESTAMP(6)` field as a time and then add the results together like:

```
CAST(CAST(A AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (CAST(A AS TIME(6)) - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
```

You can also use `SUBSTRING()` to snip off the last 6 characters of the `TIMESTAMP(6)` field and cast that resulting string to a `TIMESTAMP(0)`:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(A AS CHAR(26)) FROM 1 FOR 19) AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

This doesn't address the `INVALID TIMESTAMP` error you are getting though. Are you certain that field `A` is a `TIMESTAMP(6)` and not a `VARCHAR()` that looks like a Timestamp? What happens when you remove the outer cast, are their any dates in the result that look like they wouldn't convert nicely to a timestamp? Something is not quite right here, and I suspect that it's in your data.